# Why is identity map on a separable Hilbert space not compact? False proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Why is identity map on a separable Hilbert space not compact? False proof.

Let $e_n$ be the orthonormal basis. Then the projection map onto $H$ is defined by $\sum(x,e_k)e_k$. What is stopping us from taking a finite part of this series. This gives us a compact operators, that converge to the identity map. Clearly something is wrong here not all Hilbert spaces are finite dimensional.

Comment: I think you should add infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacause that sequence of operators does *not* converge to the identity: if $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\left\lVert e_{n+1}-\sum_{j=1}^n\langle e_{n+1},e_k\rangle e_k\right\rVert=\lVert e_{n+1}\rVert=1$$and therefore$$\left\lVert\operatorname{Id}-\sum_{k=1}^n\langle\cdot,e_k\rangle e_k\right\rVert\geqslant1.$$

Comment: Doesn't the series $\sum (x,e_k)e_k$ converge to $x$?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The series you gave would actually give you $e_{n+1}$. It is $\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}(x,e_k)e_k=x$ ?Is the standard projection onto $H$

Comment: That's not the strong operator topology. It's the strong (or weak) topology on the Hilbert space. There are several topologies to keep in mind in functional analysis settings.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ohh it converges point wise to the identity , right?

Comment: Will you please wait until I answer to a comment before you post another one? Which series are you talking about? There is no series in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it converges pointwise, not in the operator norm.